# Oath2 implementation for React and spring boot

Tags: java, reactjs, spring-boot, oauth, oauth-2.0

I am trying to secure my application using OAuth. I have client application(UI) build in react and back-end is in Spring Boot. I have an OAuth server configured which will be taking care of authenticating the user.

I am really confused if React application should talk to Auth server and get the token or Spring Boot should get the token.

After reading multiple articles I thought about flows:

1. User will go to ReactApp home page and ReactApp will redirect it to OAuth Server login page(`/authorize`)
2. OAuth server will authenticate the user credential and redirect the user to ReactApp home page with `code`
3. ReactApp will send the code to Spring Boot server using the API endpoint
4. Spring Boot server will use the `code`(along with client Id and client secret) and get the `token` from Auth Server and send that token to ReactApp for further communication

Question:

1. Is this the standard flow?
2. How secure the application is using this flow?
3. Is it a good idea to do some part in UI and another part of authentication in the backend ?(`code` in UI(ReactApp) and `token` in back-end(Spring Boot))?
4. Is there any better way than this?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The SPA is the *client* and the Spring Boot application is the *resource server*. There's [an out-of-the-box integration](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security-oauth2-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-security-oauth2-resource-server) to set up your Boot service. Ideally, your React application will use the `authorization_code` flow and exchange the code for the token itself, then send the token to the Boot service. [Possibly useful.](https://medium.com/@mattmazzola/react-simple-auth-react-redux-oauth-2-0-de6ea9df0a63)

Comment: React can not get the `token` since to get the `token` from `code` ReactApp need to pass `Client ID` and `Client Secret` which is not secure. That why I though of sending the `code` to Spring Boot and let the spring boot get the `token` and pass it to ReactApp.

Comment: React will be a _public client_ in this case; you're correct that you have either no client secret or a non-secret client "secret", but that's still better than the alternatives.

Comment: So, the flow I have mentioned is not secure or will not work ?

Comment: In the flow you've mentioned, there is no purpose in having a separate OAuth2 server. You need to review an OAuth2 tutorial and define the roles of _authorization server_, _resource server_, and _client_ in your system.

Comment: I am in the ecosystem where I have to use authorization server which knows the user name and password hence I have to use that server. Looks like I have to make Spring Boot as a backend to ReactApp which makes it tightly coupled.

Comment: You don't _have_ to, you just don't want to follow the standard practice of using a _public client_. That's a defensible design choice, but it's not something that you're forced into.

Comment: So you suggest using one of this standard practice: Authorization Code Grant using Proof Key for Code Exchange (PKCE) and the Implicit Grant.

Comment: Precisely. If your OAuth2 server doesn't support PKCE (which is useful but still very new), then it is slightly less preferable but really not much of a practical problem to use an unauthenticated public client.

Comment: When you say unauthenticated public client you mean _Implicit Grant_ flow? If not, can you please tell me the methodology name? any link will be appreciated.

Comment: No, I mean using the `authorization_code` flow but either omitting the client secret entirely (a pain with Spring Security's OAuth2 Authorization Server) or acknowledging that it's not "secret" and setting the permitted scopes/token expiration accordingly.

Comment: I see. Unfortunately, Authorization Server is handled by another team and I am afraid they would configure their server to omit client secret. They will stick to standards. I guess [Implicit Flow](https://auth0.com/docs/flows/concepts/implicit) is the only option left for me.